# Raw jpg post from flash to php. How to save the jpg image? The image is corrupted

Tags: php, file-io, jpeg

I am getting a raw jpg post from flash into a php script and saving the image in a temp folder in the server. The image is saved, the size is correct, but when I try to open it I get an error message saying that it is corrupted.

Here is the php code that I am using:

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$result = file_put_contents("imagePathOntheServer/image.jpg",$data);
echo $result;
?>
```

Any ideas? 
Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried viewing the file in a text editor? Are the headers in tact? The first possibility that occurs to me is you're getting HTTP header information in your stream...

Comment: You should really look in to POSTing the information to the page and using the `multipart/form-data` MIME type if you're working with files (esp. binary). ([php docs reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php#62380))

Comment: Mjec - when I "echo $data" and check it on Charles, I can see that the response as an image (not corrupted). But when I check the file on the server it is corrupted. How do I go about checking the HTTP header? Thank you!

Comment: mjec - I did check the file in notepad and I compared with the original. They are pretty much the same.